# JSON Decoder in Elm 0.18

Tags: json, elm, decoder

In Elm 0.18, I would like to build a JSON decoder for the following examples:

case 1:

```
{"metadata": {"signatures":[{"metadata": {"code": "1234"}},
                            {"metadata": {"code": "5678"}}]}}  

-> { code = Just "1234" }
```

case 2:

```
{"metadata": {"signatures":[]}} 

-> { code = Nothing }
```

case 3:

```
{"metadata": {"signatures":[{"metadata": null}]}} 

-> { code = Nothing }
```

This is what I got working, but it fails for case 3.

```
type alias Code = { code : Maybe String }

let
    js = """{"metadata": {"signatures":[{"metadata": {"code": "1234"}},
                   {"metadata": {"code": "5678"}}]}}"""

    dec1 =
        Decode.at [ "metadata", "code" ] Decode.string

    dec0 =
        Decode.list dec1
            |> Decode.andThen
                (\v ->
                    if List.isEmpty v then
                        Decode.succeed Nothing
                    else
                        Decode.succeed <| List.head v
                )

    dec =
        decode Code
            |> optionalAt [ "metadata", "signatures" ] dec0 Nothing

    expected =
        Ok { code = Just "1234" }
in
    Decode.decodeString dec js
        |> Expect.equal expected
```

A workaround would be to import all the data to the model and then obtain the info from the model, but I prefer to avoid adding unnecessary data into my model. How can I improve this?

Comment: What output are you getting for the second string? I ran your code and I'm getting `Ok { code = Nothing }` for the second string.

Comment: Your decoder [works for me](https://ellie-app.com/D7RFyXhzxLa1). Note that `dec0` can be shortened to `Decode.list dec1 |> Decode.map List.head`

Comment: Working example of your code is at https://ellie-app.com/D8WTFxc73Sa1

Comment: You guys are right, it works for both cases, I added the third one which is the problematic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more simplified approach could use `Json.Decode.index` to force the decoding at index zero as a string if it exists, which will fail otherwise, so you can use `Json.Decode.maybe` to return `Nothing` on failure.

```elm
dec0 =
    Decode.maybe (Decode.index 0 dec1)
```